# Running pdftk on a shared file server

Tags: cmd, shared, pdftk, fileserver

I have pdftk installed on a shared file server, and it works fine from the server itself.
Is it possible to run pdftk from another computer that has access to the file server, but doesn't have pdftk installed itself?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

pdftk doesn't need to be "installed", you just run the binary executable file. If I recall correctly, it does have a dependency on the libgcc library, so this would need to be present somewhere the system can automatically find it (like /windows/system32 on windows, or /lib | /lib64 on linux systems). Then you would just need to make sure the fileserver shares the folder that contains the pdftk binary executable and proper permissions are given.